# How the heck does this compile to 4kb?

Tags: c, optimization, avr, avr-gcc

```
#define F_CPU 1000000

#include <stdint.h>
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

const uint8_t sequences[] = {
    0b00000001, 
    0b00000011,
    0b00000110,
    0b00001100,
    0b00011000,
    0b00110000,
    0b00100000,
    0b00110000,
    0b00011000,
    0b00001100,
    0b00000110,
    0b00000011,
    0b00000001,
};

const uint8_t totalSequences = sizeof(sequences) / sizeof(sequences[0]);

int main(void) {
    DDRB = 0b00111111;

    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t b;

    while(1) {
        for(i = 0; i < totalSequences; i++) {
            const uint8_t currentSequence = sequences[i];
            const uint8_t nextSequence = sequences[(i + 1) % totalSequences];

            // blend between sequences
            for(b = 0; b < 100; b++) {
                PORTB = currentSequence;  _delay_us(b);
                PORTB = nextSequence;     _delay_us(100-b);
            }

            _delay_ms(50);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the entirety of my program.  When I was setting PORTB directly (without the blend) like below, the compiled binary is 214 bytes.  When I include the second for loop, my compiled binary is over 4kb.  I only have 1kb of FLASH available so I need to fit this in there.

```
const uint8_t currentSequence = sequences[i];
const uint8_t nextSequence = sequences[(i + 1) % totalSequences];

//// blend between sequences
//for(b = 0; b < 100; b++) {
//  PORTB = currentSequence;  _delay_us(b);
//  PORTB = nextSequence;     _delay_us(100-b);
//}

PORTB = currentSequence;
PORTB = nextSequence;
_delay_ms(50);
```

My toolchain is WINAVR, compiled with the following:

```
avr-gcc -Os -mmcu=attiny13 -Wall -std=c99 main.c -o main.out
avr-objcopy -O binary main.out main.bin
```

I don't know enough to decompile the binary and see what the compiler did, but whatever it was, it was wrong.  Why is the binary with the inner loop 4kb, and how I can fix it?

Revised loop  (278 bytes):

```
while(1) {
    for(i = 0; i < totalSequences; i++) {
        const uint8_t currentSequence = sequences[i];
        const uint8_t nextSequence = sequences[(i + 1) % totalSequences];

        // blend between sequences
        for(b = 0; b < 100; b++) {
            int d;
            PORTB = currentSequence;  for(d = 0; d < b; d++,   _delay_us(1));
            PORTB = nextSequence;     for(d = 100; b < d; d--, _delay_us(1));
        }

        _delay_ms(50);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the map file.  You should be able to get GCC to produce a map file by adding `-Wl,-Map=output.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delay() function blows up the code size unless the parameter is a compile time constant. It also won't delay for the correct time with a variable parameter.

Comment: please check my revised loop in the OP.  The compiled binary is now 278 bytes.  Will that one work better?